# T-SQL Merge with multiple options in Matched scenario

Tags: t-sql, merge, azure-sql-database, ssms-2017

So I did some digging around on this site and no dice except for a case statement to update two columns in SQL Merge. I have another issue. Can you do two option in a matched scenario? I want to do an Update and an insert on a When Matched. Is this possible? Can you please post an example?
My end goal is to update the older record and insert a new record in the target table.

```
 Merge Table1 as targ
using Table2 as sour

on table1ID  = Table2ID 

When  MATCHED 

    Then  update col1 = sour.col2 

    Then insert (col1,col2,col3)
    values (sour.col1,sour.col2,sour.col3)

When Not Matched 

    Then insert (col1,col2,col3)
    values (sour.col1,sour.col2,sour.col3);
```

Comment: The merge grammar is here. This answers your question. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

I wrap my [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statements in a transaction on a [rollback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/rollback-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and check the output. A `MERGE` statement can also be the last part of a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as well. You can have multiple `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` statements within a `MERGE` with different `WHERE` clauses.

> Note: In a merge statement, there can't be multiple rows per the columns in the join.

#### Code:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON  --When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    MERGE Table1 AS T
    USING Table2 AS S
        ON --<< Update the join to the correct unique key for the table (can't have duplicate rows)
            T.[col1] = S.[col1]
        AND T.[col2] = S.[col2]
        AND T.[col3] = S.[col3]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET -- AND 1=2 --<< you can include a where clause here
        THEN INSERT
        (
           [col1], [col2], [col3]
        )
        VALUES
        (
           S.[col1], S.[col2], S.[col3]
        )
    WHEN MATCHED  -- AND 1=2 --<< you can include a where clause here
        THEN UPDATE SET
          T.[col1] = S.[col1]
        , T.[col2] = S.[col2]
        , T.[col3] = S.[col3]
    --WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE -- AND 1=2 --<< you can include a where clause here
        --THEN DELETE
    OUTPUT @@SERVERNAME AS [Server_Name], DB_NAME() AS [Database_Name], $action, inserted.*, deleted.*;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
--COMMIT TRANSACTION;

GO
```